# PHP Spreadsheet populate db with all column's rows

Tags: php, laravel, spreadsheet

Hello i have this portion of code:

```
    $request->validate([
        'uploaded_file' => 'required|file|mimes:xls,xlsx'
    ]);

    $excel_file = $request->file('uploaded_file');
    $file = IOFactory::load($excel_file->getRealPath());

    $worksheet = $file->getActiveSheet();
    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

    $data_detail = [];

    for ($row = 9; $row < $highestRow; $row++) {

        $data_detail['codice_articolo'] = $worksheet->getCell("A$row")->getValue();
        $data_detail['quantita'] = $worksheet->getCell("B$row")->getValue();
        $data_detail['prezzo'] = $worksheet->getCell("C$row")->getValue();

    }
```

Excel

[image]

DB:

[image]

I'm struggling to populate the db with rows as they are in the excel file but it's only recording first row

Comment: `$data_detail['codice_articolo'] =`...etc, every time you run the `for` loop this just overwrites the same value in the data_detail array. Perhaps you intended to append to this array instead?

Comment: yes i should append first in the $data_detail = []; because then i save to db by this way:
$new_orders_details->codice_articolo = $data_detail['codice_articolo'];
$new_orders_detail->save();

Comment: I think what you probably want in the loop is `for ($row = 9; $row < $highestRow; $row++) {
$newEntry = array();
        $newEntry['codice_articolo'] = $worksheet->getCell("A$row")->getValue();
        $newEntry['quantita'] = $worksheet->getCell("B$row")->getValue();
        $newEntry['prezzo'] = $worksheet->getCell("C$row")->getValue();
$data_detail[] = $newEntry;
    }` . This will create a new associative array and add it to data_detail. data_detail then becomes a list of entries, rather than only containing a single entry.

Comment: Then later on you can loop through data_detail and insert each entry as a row in the database

Comment: Thank you very much that what i was trying to do! But now i'm looping on data_detail like this: 
            foreach($data_detail as $i => $row_detail) {
                $new_orders_details->codice_articolo = $row_detail[$i]['codice_articolo'];
                $new_orders_details->quantita = $row_detail[$i]['quantita'];
                $new_orders_details->prezzo = $row_detail[$i]['prezzo'];
            }
But i'm getting this error: Trying to access array offset on value of type int

Comment: You don't need the `[$i]` bit. $row_detail is already the associative array. If you're ever confused about the structure of an array, just use `var_dump` to debug it - e.g. `var_dump($row_detail);` and you'll see what's inside it.

Comment: Great. I added it as a formal answer below now, so you can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here: `$data_detail['codice_articolo'] =` ...etc: every time you run the for loop this just overwrites the same value in the data_detail array. It seems you intended to append to this array instead.

Use this:

```
for ($row = 9; $row < $highestRow; $row++) { 
  $newEntry = array();         
  $newEntry['codice_articolo'] = $worksheet->getCell("A$row")->getValue();         
  $newEntry['quantita'] = $worksheet->getCell("B$row")->getValue();         
  $newEntry['prezzo'] = $worksheet->getCell("C$row")->getValue(); 
  $data_detail[] = $newEntry;     
}
```

This will create a new associative array and add it to `$data_detail`. `$data_detail` then becomes a list of entries, rather than only containing a single entry.

Then later on you can loop through `$data_detail` and include it in your dataset for updating the database, e.g.:

```
foreach($data_detail as $i => $row_detail) { 
  $new_orders_details->codice_articolo = $row_detail['codice_articolo']; 
  $new_orders_details->quantita = $row_detail['quantita']; 
  $new_orders_details->prezzo = $row_detail['prezzo']; 
}
```

Comment: Clear guide! thanks a lot!